# Do closed questions contribute to rep?

Tags: support

Yes, this is an unabashed effort to gain rep/badges :)

Do questions that get closed or migrated still contribute to a user's track ? I'm thinking edits, tag badge upvotes, reviews etc

Comment: Points on a question that gets migrated are similarly migrated. Closed questions you keep unless they are deleted. Watch for the dreaded 'recalc'!

Comment: Also, if you are looking for some easy rep, you can find lots of low-hanging fruit, where the answers are in the comments and all you have to do is put the answer in and post it. This one http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61387/child-accompanied-visa-returning-alone  and this one http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61387/child-accompanied-visa-returning-alone  lots more out there :)

Answer (score 1):

Closed questions are no different from open questions except that no *new* answers can be added to them. Most importantly, closed questions can:

- attract votes (both up and down)
- be edited by anyone (users without the edit priviledge will need to get their edit accepted);
- their answers can be voted on (both up and down)
- answers can be accepted, unaccepted, reaccepted
- answers can be edited, deleted and undeleted.

All of the above bullet point generate reputation in some way and that reputation is in no way different from reputation gained or lost from open questions.

Only deletion of answers and questions causes a reputation reversal, if deletion is done according to a set of rules that I am not to firm on. (i.e. reproducibly, reputation sometimes gets refunded and sometimes doesn’t; I’m just too lazy to look up the rules.)

Of course, any badges you may or may not get because of editing, voting or posting will still be awarded if the corresponding actions are performed on closed questions; the same goes for Winterbash hats. (Explicitly excluding those cases where the explicit caveat is mentioned either in the badge description or the hat description.)

This is different to questions that have been migrated and/or locked; the two are just two flavours of the same feature. In those cases, the question is not considered a good example of an on-topic question on this site; thus votes can no longer be given, comments and answers no longer posted and posts no longer edited *on this site.* Therefore, no more reputation is gained and no badges/hats can be won. I specifically mentioned ‘on this site’ because migrated questions, naturally, move somewhere else. On ‘somewhere else’, they are open questions and the normal mechanisms apply again (just not ‘here’).